# indy-10.2.0.1/fpc/IdStackUnix.pas(610,19) Error: Identifier not found "socket"

Tags: compiler-errors, debian, lazarus, indy10

I downloaded Indy10 for Lazarus, but when I try to compile it I get this error:

> "indy-10.2.0.1/fpc/IdStackUnix.pas(610,19) Error: Identifier not found
>   "socket""

How to fix it?
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I never had luck to install Indy on Lazarus from scratch using official repo. I can propose 3 ways: 1) ask your question at the Lazarus official forum; 2) use the adapted Indy from other sources (I have luck with [CodeTyphon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/), to get Indy from it: `CodeTyphonIns.zip/installbin/allzips/src/typhon_src.7z/typhon/components/pl_Indy` and change package requirement `bs_ideintf` to `IDEIntf`) and 3) look at [other networking libraries](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Networking_libraries).

Comment: That sounds correct. There are no supported units with an identifier "socket" in them for unix. Sounds like you have an old version that switches to Kylix compatibility if not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

10.2.0 is a *VERY* old version of Indy.  This is clearly stated on Indy's download page:

> Download source from the [Development Snapshot](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.aspx) and extract the source files to a folder of your choosing on your PC.
>
> An **older code** from the version control system that was organized into a sensible distribution.  This was updated on **11/13/2007**.  Please read the README file included with this distribution.
>
> •indy-10.2.0.3.zip - for Windows users.
>  
>   •indy-10.2.0.3.tar.gz  - for Unix/Linux system users.

The current Indy version is 10.6.2.  The old FPC release no longer applies, it was merged into the main codebase a LONG time ago.  `IdStackUnix.pas` no longer calls `socket()` directly, it now calls FreePascal's [`fpsocket()`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sockets/fpsocket.html) function instead.  You need to [download an up-to-date version](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.aspx).

Comment: In fact, I already tried to use this version but I had an error during the installation : "lazarus.pp: Can't find unit lclbase used by lazarus". how to fix this one? I tried to add lclbase package to indylaz, but it didn't solve the problem, what's more there is no unit with this name in indy folder!

Comment: AFAIK Indy does not use `lclbase`. There are plenty of discussions on the [FreePascal/Lazarus forum](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/) describing how to install Indy in Lazarus.